# Xml Schema with "xmlns"

Tags: xml, xsd

I need more clarification in the question/answer posted here, 
[Custom attributes in an xsd-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084155/custom-attributes-in-an-xsd-schema)

There was the following xsd,

```
<xsd:element name="Book">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string" >
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <foo:listable value="true"/>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
             </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Pages" type="xsd:int" />
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

in this, speciying the following url

xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/bar"

what will be the content of this url and how to create it?

Answer (score 3):

> `xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/bar"`
>
> what will be the content of this url and how to create it?

That isn't a URL. It is a namespace identifier. It looks like a URL to reduce the likelihood of a namespace collision.

It is traditional to put some form of human readable documentation at the URL that matches the name of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the relationship between schemas, instance documents, and namespaces. I'm not sure what the confusion is, but the effect is that your question simply doesn't make sense. It's a bit like showing us a schema and saying "given this schema, what is the price of a pint of beer?"